# Piping bash commands using Python subprocess.call - Syntax error: "|" unexpected

Tags: python-3.x, shell, syntax, subprocess, pipe

I was testing pipe using subprocess.call and I came to the following problem.
For example an automated ssh using users as strings and as a text file.
The pipe works perfectly using strings (Example 1) but it fails when opening a text file to check the users (Example 2).
Is there a limitation when piping values from a file?

Example 1:
$ python3 script.py myhost

```
import subprocess 
import sys
host = sys.argv[1]
for j in range(0, 2):  
  words = ['test1', 'test2']
  user = words[j]
  print(user)
  print('Loggin in %s...' % repr(user))
  subp = subprocess.call(['echo %s | ssh %s' % (user, host)], 
  shell=True, stdout=None, stderr=None)
```

Output:

test1

Trying 'test1'...

Logged in

test2

Trying 'test2'...

Logged in

Example 2:
$ python3 script.py myhost users.txt

```
import subprocess 
import sys
host = sys.argv[1]
user_list = sys.argv[2]
with open(user_list) as usr:
    user = usr.readline()
    cnt = 0
    while user:
       print(user.strip())
       user = usr.readline()
       subp = subprocess.call(['echo %s | ssh %s' % (user, host)],
       shell=True, stdout=None, stderr=None)
       cnt += 1
```

Output:

test1

/bin/sh: 2: Syntax error: "|" unexpected

test2

/bin/sh: 2: Syntax error: "|" unexpected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone stumbles into this, I ended up fixing by getting rid of the first readline, adding a strip and modifying the while condition:

```
with open(user_list) as usr:
    cnt = 0
    while usr:
       line = usr.readline()
       user = line.strip()
       subp = subprocess.call(['echo %s | ssh %s' % (user, host)],
       shell=True, stdout=None, stderr=None)
       cnt += 1
```